# OCaml how to change value of iterator of for

Tags: loops, ocaml

I'm trying to modify value of iterator of for.
A mean:

```
for i = 0 to n do
   while (condition) do
      (*how in this place increment i ?*)
```

Answer (score 6):

OCaml variables are immutable. You can't change the value of `i` in your `for` loop. As cago shows, you can use a reference (an immutable variable that contains a mutable value).

However, one reason to study OCaml is to learn to program functionally, i.e., to learn how to compute without changing the values of variables. So you might want to look for another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two `while` loop:

```
let i = ref 0 in 
while !i < n do
  while (* condition *) do
      i := !i + 2
  done;
  incr i;
done
```